# Glide.js dynamic append content from Json

Tags: javascript, json, slider, carousel, glidejs

I'm trying to add content to the slider dynamically from JSON.

```
import Glide from '@glidejs/glide';

function slider() {
  let ul = document.querySelector('.glide__slides');
  let card = '';
  var glide = new Glide('.glide').destroy();

  const photo = import('../metadata/photos.json').then((module) => {
    const data = module.default;
    data.forEach((photo) => {
      console.log(photo);
      card += `<li class="glide__slide"><img src="${photo.thumbnailUrl}" alt="${photo.title}">${photo.id}</li>`;
    });
    ul.innerHTML = card;
  });

  glide.mount();
}

slider();
```

The content seems to load but the slider is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That happens because `glide.mount();` runs before the import and generate HTML finished.

So, you have to import the data and append it `then` call `glide.mount();`.

```
import Glide from '@glidejs/glide';

function slider() {
  let ul = document.querySelector('.glide__slides');
  let card = '';
  var glide = new Glide('.glide').destroy();

  const photo = import('../metadata/photos.json').then((module) => {
    const data = module.default;
    data.forEach((photo) => {
      console.log(photo);
      card += `<li class="glide__slide"><img src="${photo.thumbnailUrl}" alt="${photo.title}">${photo.id}</li>`;
    });
    ul.innerHTML = card;
  }).then(() => glide.mount());
}

slider();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help